# how to use selenium in javafx?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, javafx, java-module

error appears on the module in eclipse

Main.java(sence)

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

controller.java

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;


public class SampleController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TextArea output;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        output.setText(sel.getComments().toString());   
        
    }
    
}
```

sel.java

```
package application;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class sel {

    static ChromeOptions chop = new ChromeOptions();
    static WebDriver driver;
    static String url = "http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=183559&no=353&weekday=mon";
    static String[] commentsArray;

    public static String[] getComments() {
        chop.addArguments("--headless");
        chop.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chop);
        driver.get(url);
        // System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        driver.switchTo().frame("commentIframe");
        // System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        List<WebElement> comments = driver.findElements(By.className("u_cbox_contents"));
        List<WebElement> good = driver.findElements(By.className("u_cbox_cnt_recomm"));
        List<WebElement> bad = driver.findElements(By.className("u_cbox_cnt_unrecomm"));
        commentsArray = new String[comments.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i++) {
            String a;
            System.out.print(i+1 + ". ");
            System.out.println(comments.get(i).getText() + " 좋아요(" + good.get(i).getText() + ") 싫어요(" + bad.get(i).getText() + ")");
            a = Integer.toString(i+1) + ". " + comments.get(i).getText() + " 좋아요(" + good.get(i).getText() + ") 싫어요(" + bad.get(i).getText() + ")";
            commentsArray[i] = a;
        }
        return commentsArray;
    }

}
```

fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="output" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="477.0" prefWidth="474.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

module-info.java

```
module selfx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires selenium.chrome.driver;
    requires selenium.api;
    
    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

error: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module selenium.chrome.driver not found, required by selfx

i don't know why appear error...

requires selenium.chrome.driver;
requires selenium.api;
this is eclipse Recommended commands I doubt this, but I don't know how to change it.
please help..

selenium.chrome.driver;, selenium.api; changed org.seleniumhq.selenium.api;, org.seleniumhq.selenium.api.chrome.driver; but not work

Comment: How are you building this and providing dependencies and module paths at build and runtime?  Are you using Maven or Gradle?   If so, please provide the build files.

Comment: In Selenium, to launch the browser, you need 'Chromedriver.exe' and you have to configure that path in the code or you have to use WebDriverManager. But, I can't see that in your code. Even for '--headless' mode also you need it.

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/